# Are these two scripts equivalent?

Tags: script

I wonder whether

```
OP_DEPTH 0 OP_EQUAL
```

has the exact same behavior as

```
OP_DEPTH OP_NOT
```

which is

```
1 if no items
0 if any number of items
```

I'm asking because the first script is [used](https://github.com/CounterpartyXCP/cips/blob/7303fd60b603b8f38e7da703fb711f0e6c3d6377/cip-0006.md#the-redeem-script) and I'm not sure if there is any justification for that. It's very likely that they took the simple approach but I need to make sure about that since I want to squeeze the largest number of bytes out of script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general `0 EQUAL` is not equivalent to `NOT`, but in this case they are indeed equivalent.

The reason they're not equivalent in general is that `0 EQUAL` checks that the top stack element is exactly a canonical 0 push, i.e. the zero-length stack element. `NOT`, on the other hand, checks that the top stack element is **numerically** equal to 0. This means that it is between 0 and 4 bytes inclusive and all bits are zero except possibly the most significant one, which would indicate -0. If the top stack element has more than 4 bytes then `NOT` will fail the script immediately, similar to `RETURN`; there is no way to make `0 EQUAL` fail the script.

For all these reasons you should be a bit careful using `NOT` in general -- although in practice standardness rules in most of the network will prevent any of the noncanonical encodings of 0 (or any encoding of -0) to propagate. But in principle if you call `NOT` directly on witness data then this is a malleability vector.

**However**, all of this is moot because the output of `DEPTH` is guaranteed to be a canonically encoded number. So `NOT` is perfectly safe and does indeed save the extra byte.

Comment: `NOT` doesn't seem to fail if input has more than 4 bytes. I tested this by `OP_PUSHDATA1 5 0x0500000000 OP_NOT  OP_1 OP_ADD` [here](https://bitcoin-script-debugger.visvirial.com/) or `500000000 op_not 1 op_add` [here](https://siminchen.github.io/bitcoinIDE/build/editor.html)

Comment: @MCCCS then those two sites are wrong, and you shouldn't use them as script interpreters. Bitcoin Core interprets the top stack element as a number [here](https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/blob/master/src/script/interpreter.cpp#L1063) which rejects numbers bigger than 4 [here](https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/blob/master/src/script/script.h#L238-L240).